# proving subgroups on special linear groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have come across this question and actually dont think i understand completely what the question requires and how to approach such a question.Here is the question:
let n∈N+

$$
H_n : { \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}} ∈ sl(n,Z)| a=d=1(modn), b=c=0(modn)
$$
is
$
H_n $ a subgroup of sl(2,Z).
(prove)

{sl(2,Z) : special linear group.}
How do i approach such question and if someone can explain what the question is asking, paraphrase the question. What i understand now is that any identity matrix n by n is a subgroup of the the identity matrix of 2 by 2. Any help or simplification will be very much appreciated.

Comment: $sl(2,Z)$ is the group of invertible 2x2 matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ and determinant $1$. $H_n$ is a subset of this group, i.e. a set of amtrices of a special form. The question asks you to show that this subset is itself a group, i.e. a subgroup of sl(2,Z). To prove this, you need to show that 1) the product of two elements of $H_n$ is again in $H_n$ and 2) the inverse of an element of $H_n$ is again in $H_n$.

Comment: @Simon thank you  for your help.

Comment: It is sufficient to show that $\forall f,g \in H_n \implies fg^{-1} \in H_n.$.